# Где взять мотивацию программировать?

Tags: c++

Вообщем, ситуация такая. Я уже как пол года чето пытаюсь учить C++ и только щас понимаю что это безполезно, щас пытаюсь понять cs. Так вот, вроди как что то понимаю, но как реализовать знания вообще понятия нет.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме

Comment: А с какой целью учите?

Comment: Так все-таки мотивацию программировать или мотивацию что-то учить?

Comment: Я не знаю что конкретно учить, тоесть у меня есть представление что есть с++ и на нем что то можно писать, но что именно

Comment: Зачем вы вообще начали его учить? Что вы хотите/хотели делать с его помощью?

Comment: Конкретной цели нет, но что-то написать на плюсах очень хочется

Comment: калькулятор напишите, прекрасная цель для начала.

Comment: *"что-то написать на плюсах очень хочется"* - месье знает толк...

Comment: Я бы для начала выбрал какую-нибудь конкретную задачу. Что-нибудь интересное, что будет мотивация делать. (Какую-нибудь игру? Что-то еще?)

Comment: А что обычно на c++ пишут? Помимо игр

Comment: попробовать поработать на рытье траншей или охранником, может тогда появится мотивация

Comment: _пытаюсь понять cs_ - Что такое cs? [Computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science)?

Comment: *"что обычно на c++ пишут"* Да что хотите (только не сайты).

Comment: Да, computer science, щас взялся за книгу "Операционнные системы" Таненбаума, прочитал 2 глав, но понял процентов 40% всего материала

Comment: Присоединяюсь к совету выше: поработайте на тяжелом физическом труде (гастарбайтером на любой стройке). Ещё можно в армию сходить - хорошо мозги прочищает, лол. Мотивация сразу появится.